# How to update The Samsung galaxy S2(GT-I9100) to 4.1.2 Via Ubuntu 12.10(AMD64)

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, updates, 4.1-jelly-bean

The title sais is all

**Question**:How to update The Samsung galaxy S2(GT-I9100) to 4.1.2

**Note**: *I am using Ubuntu 12.10*

Comment: You will have to wait till it's distributed for over-the-air updates. Or you root it.

Comment: Most probably using **kies** if they have any version for Ubuntu or you can use **Odin** also if they have made any version for Ubuntu. Or you can use Virtual PC and install Windows on that then use Kies for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Heimdall](http://www.glassechidna.com.au/products/heimdall/). Its a cross-platform tool suite used to flash firmware, more or less like Odin, but opensource. It has a binary that can be installed in your Ubuntu version.